# (Windows Powershell) Remove multiple appx-package at once

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-packagemanagement

I'm trying to make a Powershell script to remove unwanted appx packages, for now I know that the basic commands to remove a package is `Get-AppxPackage *PackageName* | Remove-AppxPackage`

The first thing I thought of was

```
Get-AppxPackage *PackageName1* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *PackageName2* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *PackageName3* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

with one package per line, but, It's there a way to remove multiple appx packages at once? I mean, you can set several package names in the same line of the script and each one will be eliminated, e.g. `Get-AppxPackage *PackageName1,PackageName2,PackageName3* | Remove-AppxPackage` (I know it can't be done that way).

Comment: create a list of appx items and pipe it to the get- and then the remove- cmdlets. actually, you could just pipe the list to the remove- cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

Getting every package and then removing it like the example you gave would work, but it would probably be easier to create an array with parts of the names of the packages you want to remove first. After you've created this array you can loop through it and remove every package.
Here is an example of that:

```
$appnames = @('paint','store','sticky')
foreach ($appname in $appnames)
{
  Get-AppxPackage | where-object {$_.name -match $appname} | Remove-AppPackage
}
```